# Developing a simple web designer (drag + drop of text /w fonts and images)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a client who has requested I develop a simple web designer (ala CustomInk.com's t-shirt designer) which allows users to drag & drop text and uploaded images onto a canvas.

I have some ideas about getting started with javascript/jQuery but I wanted to ask SO: What is the most universally accessible way (in terms of browser support etc.) of developing an editor like this?

Does anyone have any advice/experience in the matter before I start fooling around blindly?

Comment: For something like this I'd use Flash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cross browser support, your job will be much easier if you decide to use a Javascript library, such as jQuery. The big reason for this is because jQuery will encapsulate all of the difference between Javascript implementations between browsers. Writing this all from scratch is not really feasible.

So in your case, it sounds like you want users to select pictures and text, drag and drop them on a canvas of sorts. Then, what's your desired format for saving what they create? Are you trying to make a resulting image out of what they create?

To get started, I would check out [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com). You can use the [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable) and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable) functions for the front end, and when your users are done, you'll need to post the coordinates of their elements, text, and which pictures they're using, etc.

It seems like your biggest challenge is not making a pretty interface for this to happen, but instead, persisting what they create.

Comment: As far as persisting what they create, I'd go with serializing to json - just be careful, as json.stringify is not supported universally.

Comment: very true... I didn't even think about that.  I wonder if there's a way to use the co-ordinates to "bake" the image together into a .png or image file.  I'll do some research!

Answer (score 2):

I've recently been working on something similar - you can check out the dev site [here](http://97.107.141.248/design/new/4/2), and the js is not minified, so feel free to take what you want.

Initially I went for trying to 'render' the draft in SVG - this ended poorly, as browser support is still not that great, even using svg-web and similar libraries. I needed to do stuff like round text, and those features can really creep up on you.

In the end, I wrote a tiny python server (using [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/)) that generates a png based on a set of querystring parameters using [python-cairo](http://www.tortall.net/mu/wiki/CairoTutorial). It takes serialized json object of 'text lines' and images. The png is actually the resource, and the function itself returns a 'render.png' filebuffer, so all you have to do on the front end is change the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag and it will refresh.  I added upload functionality to the "image processing" server, too.

Since I was already serializing json that contained all the information about the design, saving that in a database and loading it to edit designs was trivial.

I would definitely recommend a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (which is what I used) to make development easier. I didn't manage to do much in the way of dragging/dropping, which is something I would probably try to do from the start if I was starting over. Feel free to email me if you'd like to see some of the back-end code or if you have any questions (my email is in my SO profile).

Comment: That's amazing, congrats!  Only thing I see in the req sheet that conflicts with this is the ability for the user to drag/drop the elements visually.

Comment: Yup, and it's something I would've liked to incorporate, but haven't figured out a way to do. The biggest problem is that the 'canvas' is rendered with each change, so it would be difficult to have draggable objects on top of it that match. Not impossible, of course...

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI is the way to go, it provides drag and srop functionality and it's cross browser. Check it examples and documentations at http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/